# Unwanted Rigid Parametric Graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to plot a parametric equation using tikz based on this [post](https://gist.github.com/windstriver/29a15f7abc1d5e192380). I end up with a rigid curve that is nothing like the desired trajectory.

I believe there is likely an issue with the way I have inputted the parametric equation. How can I fix this issue?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \draw[gray,very thin] (-3.9,-3.9) grid (3.9,3.9);
    \draw[->] (-4,0) -- (4,0) node[right] {$x(t)$};
    \draw[->] (0,-4) -- (0,4) node[above] {$y(t)$};
            
    \foreach \pos in {-3,-2,-1,2,3}
        \draw[shift={(\pos,0)}] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {$\pos$};
    \foreach \pos in {-3,-2,-1,1,2,3}
        \draw[shift={(0,\pos)}] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) node[left] {$\pos$};
              
    \fill (0,0) circle (0.064cm);
            
    \draw[thick,variable=\t,domain=-0.2:7,samples=100]
        plot ({e^(-\t)*(-2*cos(2\t)+2.3817218*sin(2\t)) },{e^(-\t)*(2.3817218*cos(2\t)+2*sin(2\t))})
              node[right] {$\bigl(x(t),y(t)\bigr)$};
              
    \fill[red] (1,0) circle (2pt)
        node [below right,yshift=-4pt] {$(1,0)$};
              
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Output Graph]

Comment: This would be much better to do in PGFPlots.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[gray, very thin] (-3.9,-3.9) grid (3.9,3.9);
\draw[->] (-4,0) -- (4,0) node[right] {$x(t)$};
\draw[->] (0,-4) -- (0,4) node[above] {$y(t)$};
\foreach \pos in {-3,-2,-1,2,3}
\draw[shift={(\pos,0)}] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {$\pos$};
\foreach \pos in {-3,-2,-1,1,2,3}
\draw[shift={(0,\pos)}] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) node[left] {$\pos$};
\fill (0,0) circle[radius=2pt];
\draw[thick, variable=\t, domain=-0.2:7, samples=100, trig format=rad, smooth]
plot ( {e^(-\t)*(-2*cos(2*\t)+2.3817218*sin(2*\t))} , {e^(-\t)*(2.3817218*cos(2*\t)+2*sin(2*\t))} )
node[above] {$\bigl(x(t),y(t)\bigr)$};
\fill[red] (1,0) circle[radius=2pt] node[below right] {$(1,0)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph of a spiral]